# Gather the values of one column based on another column of a dataframe and create list of named lists with them

Tags: r, list

I have the dataframe below:

```
name<-c("Jack","Bob","Jack","Bob")
item<-c("apple","olive","banana","tomato")
d<-data.frame(name,item)


name   item
1 Jack  apple
2  Bob  olive
3 Jack banana
4  Bob tomato
```

and I would like to create a list which will include as many lists as the unique values of `name` and each one will include the values of `item` that correspond to that `name`. The new list will be like:

```
words
[[1]]
[1] "apple"  "banana"

[[2]]
[1] "olive"  "tomato"
```

if instead of `[[1]]` and `[[2]]` I could have the actual values of `name` that correspond, `[[Jack]]` and `[[Bob]]` it would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this creating a list with `split()` and then formating the data as you wish:

```
#Code
L1 <- split(d,d$name)
L1 <- lapply(L1,function(x) {x$name<-NULL;x})
L1 <- lapply(L1,function(x) {y<- x$item;y})
```

Output:

```
L1
$Bob
[1] "olive"  "tomato"

$Jack
[1] "apple"  "banana"
```

For sure you can use `L1['Bob']` and so on to explore the list.

The fast way can be (Many thanks and credits to **@mt1022**):

```
#Code2
L <- split(d$item, d$name)
```

Output:

```
L
$Bob
[1] "olive"  "tomato"

$Jack
[1] "apple"  "banana"
```

Comment: Why not `split(d$item, d$name)`?

Comment: @mt1022 It is a valid option, I will add to the post with credit to you!

Comment: @firmo23 Always a pleasure helping!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using `aggregate`

```
> with(aggregate(. ~ name, d, list), setNames(item, name))
$Bob
[1] "olive"  "tomato"

$Jack
[1] "apple"  "banana"
```

or `tapply`

```
> with(d, tapply(item, name, c))
$Bob
[1] "olive"  "tomato"

$Jack
[1] "apple"  "banana"
```